# react-native-audio-player-recorder >> recorded on ios but can't play on android

Tags: android, ios, react-native

i am using react-native-audio-player-recorder for recording audio messages in React Native app. I managed to record on both platforms (Android & ios). The problem I'm facing is when I record an audio on ios version, I can play it on ios but not on android. I'm getting the following:

```
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 6):
Error: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
```

my code is:

```
const audioSet = {
      AudioEncoderAndroid: AudioEncoderAndroidType.AAC,
      AudioSourceAndroid: AudioSourceAndroidType.MIC,
      AVEncoderAudioQualityKeyIOS: AVEncoderAudioQualityIOSType.high,
      AVNumberOfChannelsKeyIOS: 2,
      AVFormatIDKeyIOS: AVEncodingOption.aac,
    };
    const meteringEnabled = false; 
    const path = Platform.select({
      ios: 'hello.m4a',
      android: 'sdcard/hello.mp4', // should give extra dir name in android. Won't grant permission to the first level of dir.
    });
    
    const result = await audioRecorderPlayer.startRecorder(path, audioSet, meteringEnabled);
```

As I said,

- it is recording on both platforms.
- on ios, it can play all sounds,
- on android it can play the sound only if recorded on android,